# vb6 'now' function one hour off (win7)?

Tags: windows-7, vb6

I have a vb6 program installed on thousands of machines, some XP and some Win7.  A Win7 user has called to say that the time the program applies to its events is one hour earlier than the time on the laptop clock, which is correct.  It is set to the correct time zone (Eastern) and to daylight savings time adjustment, which is the way my own Win7 machine is set up (and my own machine does not have this problem).

The line of code that obtains this time in VB6 is:

```
.IssueDate = Now
```

to put the current time and date into a member variable.

Does anyone have any ideas why a particular machine would be off by one hour, given that the clock is displaying the correct time and the time zone and DST adjustment appear correct?

Comment: Just to confirm, what does `Now()` return on its own? What is the code behind `.IssueDate`?

Comment: Here are obligatory, but not necessarily very helpful, links to the VB6 manual description of the [Now](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa445084(v=vs.60).aspx) function and the [Date data type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa262556(v=vs.60).aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to mark this one 'answered' and move on.  I asked my user, diffidently, to reboot, not really expecting it to do anything; he did and said the test case he ran did not show the error.  I asked him to call me the next time he used the system for its full-blown purpose, but he hasn't done so.  My current suspicion is that the PC clock was off by an hour for a period this morning and he didn't notice it, he only noticed the time on the documents the application was producing.